# Transpose values in column based on key value in other column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'd like to make a kind of tranposition for the following input table based on column B5. In output show unique values of B5 and tranpose all values in B3 related with the same value in B5.

```
+----+----+-------+----+----+
| B1 | B2 |   B3  | B4 | B5 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 |  1624 |  M | 11 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 |  4606 |  M | 12 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 |  4609 |  M | 12 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 |  4630 |  M | 12 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 |  4690 |  M | 12 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 | 25660 |  M | 27 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 | 73003 |  M | 28 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 | 73006 |  M | 28 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 | 73008 |  M | 28 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
|  R |  1 | 73013 |  M | 28 |
+----+----+-------+----+----+
```

[image]

Below my current steps but getting not expected output.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"B1", type text}, {"B2", Int64.Type}, {"B3", Int64.Type}, {"B4", type text}, {"B5", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"B5", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"B5", type text}}, "en-US")[B5]), "B5", "B1")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Please some help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblData"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"B1", type text}, {"B2", Int64.Type}, {"B3", Int64.Type}, {"B4", type text}, {"B5", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Cleaned Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"B1", Text.Clean, type text}, {"B4", Text.Clean, type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Cleaned Text",{"B1", "B2", "B4"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"B5"}, {{"tblB3", each _, type table [B3=nullable number, B5=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "lstB3", each Table.Column([tblB3],"B3")),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"tblB3"}),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns1", {"lstB3", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "lstB3", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"lstB3.1", "lstB3.2", "lstB3.3", "lstB3.4"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"lstB3.1", Int64.Type}, {"lstB3.2", Int64.Type}, {"lstB3.3", Int64.Type}, {"lstB3.4", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

That's the output I get

[image]

The M-code above has the disadvantage that it will not generate the correct number of columns if you add or remove something to the data.

If you look at the data set

[image]

the output is

[image]

but it should be

[image]

This is becasue the query above only considers the number of delimiters when the query was created.

With the following two queries one can fix the issue.
The following query will prepare the data (define it as *connection only*)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblData"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"B1", type text}, {"B2", Int64.Type}, {"B3", Int64.Type}, {"B4", type text}, {"B5", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Cleaned Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"B1", Text.Clean, type text}, {"B4", Text.Clean, type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Cleaned Text",{"B1", "B2", "B4"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"B5"}, {{"tblB3", each _, type table [B3=nullable number, B5=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "B3", each Table.Column([tblB3],"B3")),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"tblB3"}),
    tblToSplit = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns1", {"B3", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text})
in
    tblToSplit
```

The seconnd query based on the code [here](https://www.goodly.co.in/split-by-variable-columns-in-power-query/) will dynamically split the column

```
let
  Source = tblSplit,
  DynamicColumnList = List.Transform({
    1..List.Max(
      Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Count(
        Text.PositionOfAny([B3], {","}, Occurrence.All)
      ))[Custom]
    ) + 1
  }, each "B3." & Text.From(_)),
  #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(
    Source, 
    "B3", 
    Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
    DynamicColumnList
  )
in
  #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Comment: many thanks for your explanation. It seems to work pretty nice! Only one question. If the number of columns is greater, only I need to change the name of the columns where the values for B4 and B3 are in this sample?

Comment: I am not sure if I got your question. Are you talking about the columns in the data set you start with? Or are you talking about the number of columne in the result data set? Could you explain?

Comment: I mean, have more columns in input table and B3 an B5 have different columns positions. For example B3 could be in position of column 10 and B5 could be in position of column 12. The output would have the same information, only B5 and B3_1 to B3_n.

Comment: Ok, that is not a problem. But, of course, you have to adjust the steps where these not necessary columns are being used.

Comment: I've been trying and it works for me when I change the names of the columns and using Remove other columns following your same logic. I think that would be the way. Thanks so much for your help. Regards